# Swift 3, Extending an Objective-C generic class with a function that takes a closure

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, swift3

I'm using an objective-c lib that defines a generic class like:

```
@interface BFTask<__covariant ResultType> : NSObject
```

I need to add a function to this class. As soon as the function declares a parameter which is a closure, I get an error. So

```
extension BFTask { func noClosure(param1: Int) { } }
```

compiles fine while

```
extension BFTask { func withClosure(param1: (Int) -> Void) { } }
```

Results in "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11"

Comment: Is it your program that's segfaulting, or the compiler?

Comment: The program doesn't compile.

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug report...

Comment: I just did that. Lets see what happens.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Comment: Still no answer, I promise to update when I get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved in Xcode 8.1.

Comment: It's still happening for me if I use something like `@interface MyClass<__covariant Type: MyClass *> : NSObject`.